# which side will initiate the version negotiation in the SSH transport layer protocol?

Tags: ssh

In the SSH transport layer protocol specification, http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4253.txt, section "4.2. Protocol Version Exchange", it says, "When the connection has been established, both sides MUST send an identification string.".

but it doesn't define which side shall initiate this process, the server side or the client side?

here are some observations,

1. In http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ac123/ac147/archived_issues/ipj_12-4/124_ssh.html, "Figure 2: SSH Transport Layer Protocol Packet Exchanges", the client side initiate the exchange process.
2. I tried using JSCH as client to connect server, and here is the snapshot. the server side send the SSH Protocol version first.
   [image]

And here is one issue, both JSCH and SSH server doesn't send Protocol version. 
The TCP connection is setup in package 93, 94, 95. And after 5 seconds, the server side close the connection in package 99.

can you help figure out why both client and server doesn't send out the protocol version? thanks a lot!

[image]

Regards,
Joey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we had found that some cisco box does not send its version string
without receiving the client's version string.
The recent jsch version will send it immediately.

Comment: correct. i checked the version jsch-0.1.37, and in the Session.java, it will send V_C first, then wait for server's version. while in jsch-0.1.20, it will receive the server's version first, then send out client version. so I will replace jsch with a newer version from jsch-0.1.20. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> but it doesn't define which side shall initiate this process, the server side or the client side?

Correct. As both sides must send it, and neither is defined as a response to the other, it is irrelevant who does so first.

Comment: thanks, EJP. do you know why both client and server doesn't send out the protocol version in the issue above? thanks.